# Надчёркивание или пунктирное подчёркивание текста в TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-textview

Как я могу выполнить надчёркивание ( ̅а ) + подчёркивание ( ͟а ) либо пунктирное подчёркивание (т̱а̱к̱ )в TextView?

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, например:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + text + "</u>"));
```

Выведет подчёркнутый текст.

Также посмотрите в сторону `SpannableString`:

```
        SpannableString styledString
                = new SpannableString("Подчёркнутый\n\n"
                + "Зачёркнутый\n\n");   // index 103 - 112

        styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 12, 0); 
        styledString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 13, 25, 0);


        TextView spantext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);
        spantext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        spantext.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        spantext.setText(styledString);
```

Comment: Это я знаю спасибо. Но мне нужен именно подчёркнутый пунктиром либо надчёркнутый + подчёрнутый. Хочу добавить, что моя цель это в TextView сделать так чтобы каждая буква была отделена о другой. Делаю игру угадай-слово и надо явно различать в TextView сколько пробелов стоит между буквами. Буду рад если получу альтернативные предложения решения проблемы.

Comment: @АлексейШвачко, обновила ответ